# how to generate v4UUID from my nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress

I have been looking at options to generate a v4 UUID from my nginx ingress implementation with the use of some annotations or any other way it would be possible to achieve this. I could not find any useful link to process v4 UUID yet from nginx, but wondering if it is possible at all and has someone come across a link which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [relevant search results](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=nginx+uuid&ia=software), the [simplest method](https://gist.github.com/erikcw/e999e1fb438dbbb91533#file-nginx-conf-L3) appears to be to run `luarocks install uuid` when the Ingress controller Pod starts up, then in whatever Ingress you want, generate the nginx variable as one normally would:

```lua
set_by_lua $request_uuid '
  return uuid()
'
```

If you're using this mechanism for request tracing, then you should be aware that the latest ingress-nginx releases support Open Tracing out of the box: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-opentracing

Comment: Thanks a lot @mdaniel. That link was really helpful. I will give it a shot and report back how it went.